# Abrir descarga marketplace en genexus

Tags: genexus

Alguien me puede ayudar me descargue un archivo comprimido de el marketplace de genexus pero no se como abrirlo en mi programa de genexus, me podrian por favor ayudar con detalle de los pasos...muchas gracias

Answer (score 2):

1. Descomprimir el archivo zip
2. Copiar el contenido bajo el directorio UserControls que está bajo la instalación de GeneXus.
3. Ejecutar GeneXus con el parámetro /install. Ejemplo: <GX_Installation_Path>\GeneXus /install
4. Chequear que en la toolbox se ha agregado el nuevo User Control

Importante: si se usa GeneXus Server hay que instalarlo en el server también: https://wiki.genexus.com/commwiki/servlet/wiki?26606,HowTo%3A+Installing+a+User+Control+in+GeneXus+Server

Más info:
https://wiki.genexus.com/commwiki/servlet/wiki?5920,HowTo%3A%20Installing%20User%20Controls#Manual+installation